# devise_invitable parameters disappearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

My devise worked well until a few days ago.
Seems like the parameters is lost somewhere just before the email is send:
This is the stack trace which confirms that devise is saving the email in the database:

```
Processing by Devise::InvitationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9Cj9YYy7gPbVbplSAHs+a3DkUxAYU00oMJUG11dIMAI=", "athlete"=>{"email"=>"asdfasdf@asdf.dk"}, "commit"=>"Send an invitation"}
  Admin Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Athlete Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "athletes".* FROM "athletes" WHERE "athletes"."email" = 'asdfasdf@asdf.dk' LIMIT 1
  Athlete Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "athletes" WHERE "athletes"."email" = 'asdfasdf@asdf.dk' LIMIT 1
  Athlete Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "athletes".* FROM "athletes" WHERE "athletes"."invitation_token" = 'aDop2Zd7DUSu94zydpy2' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "athletes" ("current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "invitation_accepted_at", "invitation_limit", "invitation_sent_at", "invitation_token", "invited_by_id", "invited_by_type", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["email", "asdfasdf@asdf.dk"], ["encrypted_password", ""], ["invitation_accepted_at", nil], ["invitation_limit", nil], ["invitation_sent_at", Mon, 14 Jan 2013 12:59:46 UTC +00:00], ["invitation_token", "aDop2Zd7DUSu94zydpy2"], ["invited_by_id", 1], ["invited_by_type", "Admin"], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0]]
   (619.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 701ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  devise_invitable (1.1.4) lib/devise_invitable/mailer.rb:5:in `invitation_instructions'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionmailer (3.2.11) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:458:in `process'
  actionmailer (3.2.11) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:452:in `initialize'
  actionmailer (3.2.11) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:439:in `new'
  actionmailer (3.2.11) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:439:in `method_missing'
  devise (2.2.1) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:159:in `send_devise_notification'
  devise_invitable (1.1.4) lib/devise_invitable/model.rb:168:in `deliver_invitation'
  devise_invitable (1.1.4) lib/devise_invitable/model.rb:132:in `invite!'
  devise_invitable (1.1.4) lib/devise_invitable/model.rb:240:in `_invite'
  devise_invitable (1.1.4) lib/devise_invitable/model.rb:252:in `invite!'
  devise_invitable (1.1.4) app/controllers/devise/invitations_controller.rb:16:in `create'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__4580775493151678536__process_action__2740541638652288271__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1152214596362570374__call__1601018742063366623__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'


  Rendered /Users/anderskonring/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/anderskonring/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/anderskonring/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionp
```

I have tried to work out where the error is hiding but I'm pretty sure it is pretty default configuration of devise.
The wierd thing is that my browser shows that the email is no longer a part of the parameters:

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"9Cj9YYy7gPbVbplSAHs+a3DkUxAYU00oMJUG11dIMAI=",
 "athlete"=>{},
 "commit"=>"Send an invitation"}
```

Dont know if its any help but I'm posting my routes too:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => 'home#index'

  # Devise for admins and athletes but no registration possible
  # without an invitation

  devise_for :admins do
    get 'admins/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_admins_registration'
    put 'admins' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'admin_registration'
  end

  devise_for :athletes, :except => :invitable do
    get 'athletes/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_athletes_registration'
    put 'athletes' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'athlete_registration'
  end

  # Common ressource url for both athletes and admins
  # events are nested for athletes (note: athlete --hasmany--> events)

  resources :athletes do 
    resources :events, :only => [:index, :show] 
    resources :attachments, :only => [:create, :index, :new, :destroy]
    post 'exportcal' => 'athletes#exportcal'        
  end 
  resources :admins
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing occurred to me. The issue was discussed and resolved here:

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/265

My solution:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_invitable', :git => "git://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable.git", :branch => 'master'
```

Which currently gives me:

```
Using devise (2.2.1) 
Using devise_invitable (1.1.4) from git://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable.git (at master)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow this took me quite a few hours..
Well it was a problem with the versions of devise and devise_invitable.
After hours going through the libs and the git repos I found that this combination works in my Gemfile.

```
gem 'devise', :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git", :branch => 'master'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Please comment if you know a way to use the newest versions without bugs.